# Pass .class to Clojure Function when .class is called on a Java interface

Tags: java, clojure, clojure-java-interop

I need to pass .class for a Java interface to a function call in Clojure.

Calling (class ) requires an instance of the object, where as I want the static class name.

Basically so I can java interop and use: `keysetHandle.getPrimitive(Aead.class);`

[Java Source method call](https://github.com/google/tink/blob/master/java/src/main/java/com/google/crypto/tink/KeysetHandle.java#L276)

[Interface to call .class on](https://github.com/google/tink/blob/master/java/src/main/java/com/google/crypto/tink/Aead.java)

Passing Aead but Aead is only an interface want it like so but cannot work out how to get the equivalent Aead.class in Clojure?

(.getPrimitive keyset-handle Aead.class)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried `(.getPrimitive keyset-handle Aead)`?

You should be able to pass the class of your interface just by using its name. An example Java class:

```
public class Foo {
    public <P> String bar(Class<P> klass) {
        return klass.getCanonicalName();
    }
}
```

Then in a REPL, using the `java.util.List` interface for example:

```
user=> (import Foo)
Foo
user=> (.bar (Foo.) java.util.List)
"java.util.List"
```